# Python Error of unsupported operand types for *: 'Nonetype' and 'Float' with array problem

Tags: python, arrays, function, error-handling

```
def func1(P,N):
    F1 = 0.3*P*N - 0.8*P
    return F1
def func2(P,N):
    F2 = 1.1*N + N*P

def FwEulerTwo(t0,Y0,h,tend):
    t = np.arange(t0,tend+h,h)
    n = len(t)
    Y = np.zeros((2,n))
    for i in range(0,n):
        print(Y)
        if i == 0:
            Y[0,i] = Y0[0]
            Y[1,i] = Y0[1]
        else: 
            Y[0,i] = Y[0,i-1] + func1(float(t[i-1]),float(Y[0,i-1])) * h
            Y[1,i] = Y[1,i-1] + func2(float(t[i-1]),float(Y[1,i-1])) * h

    return t,Y

Y0 = np.zeros((2,1))
print(Y0)
Y0[0,0] = 0.8
Y0[1,0] = 7
t,Y = FwEulerTwo(0,Y0,0.019,40)
```

The error I kept having is unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Nonetype' and 'float'. I am not sure what went wrong. Please help! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Python has an implicit return value: `None`.
Since in `func2` you are not returning anything, it will return None.

```
def func2(P,N):
    F2 = 1.1*N + N*P
    return F2
```